# How to I flip the contents of a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

My JSON object:

```
{   
    "AD": "Andorra",
    "AE": "United Arab Emirates"
}
```

How can I make this become:

```
{
    "Andorra": "AD",
    "United Arab Emirates": "AE"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let example = {   
    "AD": "Andorra",
    "AE": "United Arab Emirates"
};

let reversed = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(example).map(e=>e.reverse()));

console.log(reversed);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in many ways.

Using forEach loop (By traversing each item and changing key, values)

```
static flipContent(obj) {
  const res = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    res[obj[key]] = key;
  });
  return res;
}
```

Using Array.reduce() & Object.keys()

```
static flipContent(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((res, key) => {
    res[obj[key]] = key;
    return res;
  }, {});
}
```

Using Array.reduce() & Object.entries()

```
static flipContent(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((res, entry) => {
    const [ key, value ] = entry;
    res[ value ] = key;
    return res;
  }, {});
}
```